# AngularJS - Directive for getting a value in Object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently I am using this for loop for getting parent

```
angular.forEach(queryTicketCategories, function(category) {
    if(category.id === $scope.ticketCategory.parentId) {
        $scope.parent = category;
    }
});
```

Please suggest common directive that will return `category`. Here `queryTicketCategories` is an object of arrays. And I wanna assign a array to `$scope.parent` that equals `$scope.ticketCategory.parentId`

Html code is

```
   <input type="text" ng-model="parent" 
   placeholder="{{'PARENT_CATEGORY' | translate}}" 
   typeahead="category as category.name for category in getTicketCategories($viewValue)" 
   typeahead-loading="loading" class="form-control">
```

Comment: can you share code of getTicketCategories, what is its relationship with queryTicketCategories? your data-strucutre is not very clear, it would help if you provide sample data showing the data structure

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao really don't understand what exactly you wanted to achieve?

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao please update your answer with an example with some data. For example provide a `TicketCategories ` collection and for a given id what data you want to be returned. there is an inconsistency in your question.  You say " And I wanna assign a **array** to $scope.parent that equals $scope.ticketCategory.parentId" but in your code example you assign an object to it.

Comment: Adding your Data structure would help a lot!

Answer (score 7):

For your case, it's better to look into typeahead directive and make max use of it.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Instead of creating your own directive or service, you can use the existing directive with callback, `typeahead-on-select`

```
typeahead-on-select($item, $model, $label) (Defaults: null) : 
A callback executed when a match is selected
```

This is the example that I created without using callback. It enables you to select a google address from what you type.

Without `typeahead-on-select` :
http://plnkr.co/edit/GMnzod9MQZWxsKSuJUJu?p=preview

The following is going step further by changing the selected address to uppercase. You can do whatever you want in this callback.

http://plnkr.co/edit/jaeSZdSKucMQgIF05KwD?p=preview

I used this function to change the selected address to uppercase.

```
$scope.myFunc = function($item, $model, $label) {
    $scope.asyncSelected = $item.toUpperCase();
}
```

For your case you can make like the following

```
$scope.myFunc = function(category) {
    if(category.id === $scope.ticketCategory.parentId) {
        $scope.parent = category;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
typeahead-on-select="myFunc($item)"
```

In summary, your use case and data might be different from the example that I used above, but the main approach is the same. There is a callback after you select an item, and you can manipulate your data control more with the callback `typeahead-on-select`.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you want to set the `$scope.parent` object that appears in the text box based on `$scope.ticketCategory.parentId`

If so, then a directive is not the best way to do this. Directive are meant for DOM manipulation or logic that affects your view. But this functionality has nothing to do with updating view. It just happens that the view binds to `$scope.parent`, but if you just set this object in code the view will update automatically (or maybe with an `$apply()` call)

In that case, you should create a service or filter to make this operation reusable (also make sure to return once a match is found as there is no need to continue the loop after that, right?)

**However,** if you insist on using a directive. You can make a directive that depends on ng-model, and set the value of the model based on other attributes (the category list, the selected id). So the usage will be like this maybe

```
<input type="text" ng-model="parent" set-model="ticketCategory.parentId" set-model-list="queryTicketCategories" >
```

and the directive code will basically find the object from `queryTicketCategories` that has the same id as `ticketCategory.parentId` and set the model with this object.

You should probably set a flag or so in the directive to run this code only once and not every `$apply()` loop. But with the service/filter approach you get to set the `parent` value whenever you want (maybe after a server request or in a callback) so I recommend you use that instead of a directive.

Answer (score 5):

```
angular.forEach(queryTicketCategories, function(category) {
    if(category.id === $scope.ticketCategory.parentId) {
        $scope.parent = category;
    }
});
```

From your code, ***queryTicketCategories*** must be an array of objects. Since you can not loop an object. So try using,

```
angular.forEach(queryTicketCategories, function(category) {
    if(angular.equals(parseInt(category.id), parseInt($scope.ticketCategory.parentId)) {
        $scope.parent = category;
        return;
    }
});
```

Here make sure that ***queryTicketCategories*** is in the format,

```
[  { ... }
   , { ... }
   , { ... }
]
```

in order to ***category.id*** to work, and we are using parseInt since there might be a chance that ***category.id*** or ***$scope.ticketCategory.parentId*** might be in String.

Note that, '===' and angular.equals() has the same implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You can have watch expression on $scope.ticketCategory.parentId. Once the value for $scope.ticketCategory.parentId is changed then update $scope.parent to the category having the same id.for searching you can create filter.

Example -

```
app.filter('getById', function() {
  return function(queryTicketCategories, id) {
    var i=0, len=queryTicketCategories.length;
    for (; i<len; i++) {
      if (queryTicketCategories[i].id == +id) {
        return queryTicketCategories[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
});

 $scope.$watch('ticketCategory.parentId', function() {
        // do something here
       var found = $filter('getById')(queryTicketCategories, ticketCategory.parentId);
         console.log(found);
         $scope.parent = found;
    }, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you want, you have to update your answer and provide an example with what you want: i have A, i pass B, i expect C.

In any case here is a simple directive that implements the logic in the code in your question. 
And here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jx036fhg/1/).

```js
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', [])

app.controller('MyController',

  function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.myCategoryId = 11;

    $scope.myParentCategory;

    $scope.myCategories = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tara"
    }, {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Opal"
    }, {
      "id": 21,
      "name": "Whitfield"
    }, {
      "id": 31,
      "name": "Alta"
    }, {
      "id": 41,
      "name": "Tucker"
    }, {
      "id": 51,
      "name": "Sims"
    }, {
      "id": 61,
      "name": "Bradshaw"
    }];

  });



app.directive('parentCategory', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    scope: {
      categories: "=",
      categoryId: "=",
      parent: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) {

      scope.$watch('categoryId', findParent);

      function findParent() {
        var parent;
        angular.forEach(scope.categories, function(category) {
          if (category.id === scope.categoryId) parent = category;
        });
        scope.parent = parent;
      }

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="HelloApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <label for="">CategoryId:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="myCategoryId">

    <h3>Parent</h3>
    <pre>{{myParentCategory|json}}</pre>


    <parent-category categories="myCategories" category-id="myCategoryId" parent="myParentCategory"></parent-category>
  </div>
</div>


<!--     or you can use it like this, as an attribute

<input type="number" ng-model="myCategoryId" parent-category categories="myCategories" category-id="myCategoryId" parent="myParentCategory">
-->
```